# Appending HTML snippet to the view in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-renderer2

I am getting a piece of html code from a http request to an external system , and I should show this on my view in my angular app

to be percise this is the html snippet that I have to show (it will be a bit different by every request and response )

```
<div 
  id='paysonContainer'
  url='https://test-www.payson.se/embedded/checkout?id=af1ebee5-40bd-410a-90d1-a94401553414'>
</div>

<script 
  type='text/javascript' 
  src='https://test-www.payson.se/embedded/Content/payson.js?v2'>
</script>
```

I used different solution suggestions like innerHtml , but non of them is working for me (maybe because I have some script tag in my html code)

I am getting the html snippet as an string to a component and want to append it to the view (for example to a div in the view)

Comment: That html code you are getting as `string` from response? then you can simply do like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7xrqf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Don't you mean an `Iframe`?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o28ktt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: SPA aren't made to handle HTML code coming from the backend. Instead, consider making a custom script that make AJAX calls and declare it as an asset of your project.

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT    yes , I am getting it as an string inside a component (updated the question)

Comment: @AshishRanjan   you have removed the script tags - I have to add to the html code , exactly as it is. Iframe is not the solution for me

Comment: @Yashar did you check the stackblitz given by me

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT   you have showed just the url inside an iframe and removed the script , this will not work in this way.  and I may have get different structure in the html snippet and I can't pars it . I want to append it to the html and show it as a whole as it is

Comment: @Yashar I didn't use any iframe, this is my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7xrqf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT  you show it as an string on the page , not appending it to the html source code

Answer (score 2):

Can this script be wrapped in a div?

If yes, then simply use the `[innerHTML]` property binding syntax on an empty `div` and use the `str` as it's value.

After doing that though, you're going to get an unsafe scripts error which you can fix by passing it through the sanitize pipe that you can create like this:

```
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  DomSanitizer,
  SafeHtml
} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitize'
})
export class SanitizePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(html: string): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

Creating a Pipe will help you reuse this logic at several places in your App.

And in your template, you can simply use the `str` as:

```
<div [innerHTML]="str | sanitize">
</div>
```

I was able to see any content from this div on the UI.

[image]

Even the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml) says the same.

> Bypass security and trust the given value to be safe HTML. Only use this when the bound HTML is unsafe (e.g. contains  tags) and the code should be executed. The sanitizer will leave safe HTML intact, so in most situations this method should not be used.

Comment: yes , it can be wrapped in div or any other thing that you wish, but the content should be visibe. something like the content in this iframe  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o28ktt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html  
             it is the same problem that I have , content is not visible. I have not used the sanitizer but used the innerHtml and no content . will test your solution as well . will come back with the result

Comment: Okay. So does this answer help? If not, can you please update your question with the issue at hand after implementing my solution and let us know what's the issue you're facing at hand.

If this solution helped you though, consider marking this as an answer.

Comment: I am  not able to see any content , there is no exception but the div has no content

Comment: It does have content. You can inspect it and check. I did the same and I was able to see the content when I was inspecting. I wasn't able to see anything on the UI though.

Comment: it seems that I have to bypass not just html but also bypassSecurityTrustScript  and bypassSecurityTrustUrl. Since I have html and script and url in my html snippet.

Comment: I'm able to see the content without doing that.

Comment: I can't see any thing with or without inspection.  chaining the sanitizers   also not working (it seems that we can't chain sanitizer pipes). can you attach the link to the stackblitz. thanks

Comment: now I can see that in the source code html but it is not displaying on the UI, how you solve that issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try using DOMSanitizer class

```
import {BrowserModule, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.html = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<div 
  id='paysonContainer'
  url='https://test-www.payson.se/embedded/checkout?id=af1ebee5-40bd-410a-90d1-a94401553414'>
</div>') ;
  }
```