# Angular permit users to post html text with links which interact as routed links

Tags: angular

I have a textarea which permits users to store some content. My goal is to let a user add some "special" links executed as routed links after the view rendering.

Here is a base:
https://angular-fedpgb.stackblitz.io

as suggested by @Siddharth Ajmera I used a sanitizer before I set in the DOM but the link are not interpreted as router link

Is at least this possible to do with angular?

Comment: And what exactly is the issue that you're facing?

You'll have to create a route for these paths that the user is going to redirect the user on. And your user should post `routerLink` instead of `href`

Comment: That StackBlitz appears to work

Comment: as you can see now in the StackBlitz  if you replace href by routerLink this does not work and it is normal because it is the result of a bindHtml and it is sanitized WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

Comment: That's expected. You'll have to sanitize the html before you set it to the DOM.

Comment: @Siddharth Ajmera How I can di that?

Comment: I've answered that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980895/2622292

Comment: I updated my script and the link are not interpreted as links